# MS SQL query to get the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below sql query

```
SELECT Stk_Conv_Id,Created_Date,DC_Code,SKU_Name,Grade,Stock_Qty,Stock_Conv_Ref_Code
  FROM [LEAFDB].[dbo].[Stock_Convertion_Tracking] a
  where a.Created_Date between '2021-12-31' and '2021-12-31 23:59:59'
  and DC_Code ='BNG'
  order by DC_Code, Stock_Conv_Ref_Code
```

the result of SQL query given below

```
Stk_Conv_Id Created_Date    DC_Code SKU_Name              Grade Stock_Qty   Stock_Conv_Ref_Code
143590        2021-12-31    BNG     CARROT OOTY (PREMIUM)   A   995         STKC/BNG/00150
143591        2021-12-31    BNG     CARROT OOTY (RP)        A   25          STKC/BNG/00150
143592        2021-12-31    BNG     CARROT OOTY (PREMIUM)   A   970         STKC/BNG/00150
143593        2021-12-31    BNG     CARROT OOTY (BABY)      A   1.3         STKC/BNG/00151
143594        2021-12-31    BNG     CARROT OOTY (RP)        A   1.3         STKC/BNG/00151
```

I need the result as below

```
Created_Date    DC_Code From_SKU              From_Grade From_Stk_Qty To_SKU              To_Grade To_Stk_Qty Final_Stock
2021-12-31      BNG     CARROT OOTY (PREMIUM) A          995          CARROT OOTY (RP)    A        25         970
2021-12-31      BNG     CARROT OOTY (BABY)    A          1.3          CARROT OOTY (RP)    A        1.3        0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as(select *,
       row_number()over(partition by Stock_Conv_Ref_Code order by Stk_Conv_Id) seq
      from tb
      
)
select distinct Created_Date,DC_Code,

      (select SKU_Name
       from cte t2 
       where t2.seq = 1 and t1.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code = t2.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code) as From_SKU,
       
      (select Grade
       from cte t2 
       where t2.seq = 1 and t1.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code = t2.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code) as From_Grade,
       
        (select Stock_Qty
       from cte t2 
       where t2.seq = 1 and t1.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code = t2.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code) as From_Stk_Qty,
      
        (select SKU_Name
       from cte t2 
       where t2.seq = 2 and t1.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code = t2.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code) as To_SKU,
      
      (select Grade
       from cte t2 
       where t2.seq = 2 and t1.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code = t2.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code) as To_Grade,
      
      
      (select Stock_Qty
       from cte t2 
       where t2.seq = 2 and t1.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code = t2.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code) as To_Stk_Qty,
        (select Stock_Qty
       from cte t2 
       where t2.seq = 3 and t1.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code = t2.Stock_Conv_Ref_Code) as Final_Stock
from cte t1
```

*Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98bf185dc4300ea7051165f3c68c7693)*